# SetSize inside one if clause is affecting the size of the another window

Tags: java, if-statement

Here I have set size for individual Cargo ship, Cruise ship and yacht but the size of Cruise ship is being affected by size of cargo ship window. This defeats the whole purpose of if..else if ladder

```
    private static void openNewFrame(String title, BufferedImage image, ArrayList<Ship> dataFromFile) {
        JFrame newFrame = new JFrame(title);
        newFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        
        JPanel newPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

        JLabel newImageLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));
        // Add padding between the image and text
        newImageLabel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
        newPanel.add(newImageLabel, BorderLayout.WEST);

        JTextArea newTextArea = new JTextArea(10, 20);
        
        
        String text_to_be_set_in_specific_window = "";
        if (title.compareToIgnoreCase("All Yachts")>=0){
            newFrame.setSize(900, 250);
            for(Ship for_yacht:dataFromFile){
                if(for_yacht instanceof Yacht)
                {
                    Yacht yacht = (Yacht) for_yacht;
                    text_to_be_set_in_specific_window += yacht.toString()+"\n";
                    
                }
            }
        }
        else if (title.compareToIgnoreCase("All Cargo ships")>=0 ){
            newFrame.setSize(730, 250);
            for(Ship for_cargo:dataFromFile){
                if(for_cargo instanceof Cargo)
                {
                    Cargo cargo = (Cargo) for_cargo;
                    text_to_be_set_in_specific_window += cargo.toString()+"\n";
                    
                }
            }
        }else if (title.compareToIgnoreCase("All Cruise ships")>=0){
            newFrame.setSize(500, 250);
            for(Ship for_cruise: dataFromFile){
                if(for_cruise instanceof Cruise)
                {
                    Cruise cruise = (Cruise) for_cruise;
                    text_to_be_set_in_specific_window += cruise.toString()+"\n";
                }
            }           
        }

        newTextArea.setText("\n\n\n\n" + text_to_be_set_in_specific_window+" ");
        newTextArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        newTextArea.setLineWrap(true);
        newTextArea.setEditable(false);
        

        // Set the text area background color to be transparent
        newTextArea.setOpaque(false);
        Caret customCaret = new DefaultCaret() {
            @Override
            public void paint(Graphics g) {
                // Do nothing to hide the cursor
            }
        };

        // Set the custom caret for the JTextArea
        newTextArea.setCaret(customCaret);
        // Add padding between the text and the panel border
        newTextArea.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
        newPanel.add(newTextArea, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        // Create a panel to hold the button and place it on the right
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));
        JButton closeButton = new JButton("Ok");
        closeButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(80, 30)); // Set the button size
        closeButton.addActionListener(e -> newFrame.dispose());
        buttonPanel.add(closeButton);
        
        
        // Add the buttonPanel to the newPanel
        newPanel.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        newFrame.add(newPanel);
        newPanel.requestFocusInWindow();
        newFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        newFrame.setVisible(true);
        
    }
```

The section of the code which is problematic is:

```
        else if (title.compareToIgnoreCase("All Cargo ships")>=0 ){
            newFrame.setSize(730, 250);
            for(Ship for_cargo:dataFromFile){
                if(for_cargo instanceof Cargo)
                {
                    Cargo cargo = (Cargo) for_cargo;
                    text_to_be_set_in_specific_window += cargo.toString()+"\n";
                    
                }
            }
        }else if (title.compareToIgnoreCase("All Cruise ships")>=0){
            newFrame.setSize(500, 250);
            for(Ship for_cruise: dataFromFile){
                if(for_cruise instanceof Cruise)
                {
                    Cruise cruise = (Cruise) for_cruise;
                    text_to_be_set_in_specific_window += cruise.toString()+"\n";
                }
            }           
        }
```

I was trying to set the window size different for each individual cargo ship window, yacht window and cruise ship window

Comment: forgot to mention, the whole block of Cargo Ship code section is being exectued even when my title is All Cruise ships and when i comment out All Cargo Ships section then the code for All Cruise Ships executes

Comment: Do you understand what a return value `>=0` from `compareToIgnoreCase` means? Read [the method’s documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#compareToIgnoreCase(java.lang.String)) and once you understood why this does not do what you want, look for a more appropriate method in the `String` class (maybe a method telling you whether the string *equals* another). But actually, you shouldn’t make program code depending on the contents of a title string anyway. You could use an `enum` instead or better, split this into smaller reusable methods.